# Java Issue with Minecraft Realms on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, java, openjdk, minecraft, oracle

So when I first installed Ubuntu I downloaded Minecraft from the official website as a tar.gz. However when I started the launcher it gave me SSL errors, even though there was no problems with my connection. I then tried the ubuntu software center download of Minecraft which worked fine and I had no problems playing Minecraft Realms. However some time after the underwater update the outdated minecraft launcher interface was updated to the same one on Windows and that's when I noticed, after launching the game, clicking on Minecraft Realms gave me this error:

```
Could not connect to Realms: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

This seems to be similarly phrased to [this error](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/java-edition-support/2902110-minecraft-wont-launch#c9). I could swear the problem is the same one I had when I tried installing the tar.gz version.

[Similar problem](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2303600.html) was solved by running

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

this did not work for me

I've tried OracleJDK 8 and OpenJDK 8, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past the realms error by installing the updated launcher from Mojangs site:

https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/

There is also a link to it at the top of the "new launcher" that came with the underwater upgrades.

Cheers.